# Python First Letter of a word Upper CASE

Tags: python

I'm looking for some very clever and fast way of transforming every first character of a word in a string with the upper case.

```
ac milan > Ac Milan
paris saint germain > Paris Saint Germain
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use the `title` method of `str`:

```
'ac milan'.title()
```

Comment: Beware that 'lowerCamelCase' will become 'Lowercamelcase'

Comment: and 'this2that' will become 'This2That'

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
>>> "how now brown cow".title()
'How Now Brown Cow'
```